# I have to join 6 different tabel in Laravel using Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I have 6 different tables in my database and I have to fetch value from column type, id, title, created_at, updated_at, imported, import_url, cover_type, profile_image from all 6 tables and some extra values from column start_date and location from meetup table, job_location and cmp_name from job table and start_date and location from event table. I am using union() function but it is not working as to join select statement from different table using union we should have same number of columns.

```php
public function wsUserActivity() {
    $request = Input::all();
    try {
        $user_id = $request['user_id'];
        $no = isset($request['page_number']) ? $request['page_number'] : 0;
        $nos = isset($request['count']) ? $request['count'] : 10;
        $skp = $no * $nos;
        $array_json_return = array('status' => '1','msg' => 'Success');
        $u_activity = array();
        $u_article = DB::table('mst_article as article')
        ->select(DB::raw('"article" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');
        $u_meetup = DB::table('mst_meetup as meetup')
        ->select(DB::raw('"meetup" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%d %b %Y") as start_date'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image', 'location')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');
        $u_question = array();
        $u_question = DB::table('mst_question as question')
        ->select(DB::raw('"question" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');
        $u_job = array();
        $u_job = DB::table('mst_job as job')
        ->select(DB::raw('"job" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image', 'job_location', 'cmp_name')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');
        $u_education = array();
        $u_education = DB::table('mst_education as education')
        ->select(DB::raw('"education" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');
        $u_activity= DB::table('mst_event as event')
        ->select(DB::raw('"event" as type'),'id','title', DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(created_at, "%d %b %Y") as created_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(updated_at, "%d %b %Y") as updated_at'), DB::raw('DATE_FORMAT(start_date, "%d %b %Y") as start_date'), 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image', 'location')
        ->selectRaw('SUBSTRING(`description`, 1, 200) as `description`')
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->union($u_article)
        ->union($u_question)
        ->union($u_meetup)
        ->union($u_job)
        ->union($u_education)
        ->skip($skp)
        ->take($nos)
        ->get();
        if (count($u_activity) > 0) {
            foreach ($u_activity as $key => $value) {
                if (!empty($value->profile_image)) {
                    $u_activity[$key]->profile_image_url = config("feature_pic_url").'type_image/thumb/'.$value->profile_image;
                }
                $u_activity[$key]->post_url = url('/') . '/view-type' .  '/' . $value->id;
            }
        }
        $array_json_return['u_activity'] = $u_activity;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        $array_json_return = $this->api_default_fail_response(__function__, $e);
    }
    echo json_encode($array_json_return);
}
```

Comment: What is the result you expect? Maybe using collection methods might be simpler than using sql unions

Answer (score 0):

I had the issue same as you are having.

Keep the same columns as it is.

- type, id, title, created_at, updated_at, imported, import_url, cover_type, profile_image

However the extra column you have, those need to concat in to one column with some unique separation sign like "," or ":" whatever fits best in your case.

Here is an example you can use as reference.

```
$u_education = DB::table('mst_education as education')
        ->select('type', 'id', 'title', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image',DB::raw('CONCAT("extra_column_1",",","extra_column_2") as extra_col'))
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1');
        $u_activity= DB::table('mst_event as event')
        ->select('type', 'id', 'title', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'imported', 'import_url', 'cover_type', 'profile_image',DB::raw('CONCAT("extra_column_1",",","extra_column_2") as extra_col'))
        ->where('user_id_fk',$user_id)
        ->where('status', '=', '1')
        ->union($u_article)
        ->union($u_question)
        ->union($u_meetup)
        ->union($u_job)
        ->union($u_education)
        ->skip($skp)
        ->take($nos)
        ->get();
```

Now when you get result, process them through foreach loop and separate those column by using "," separation we used.

Here is example for reference.

```
$results = [];
if (sizeof($u_education) > 0)
{
    foreach ($u_education as $key => $value) {
        $results[$key][] = $value->id;
        $extra_col = explode("," , $value->extra_col);
        $results[$key]['extra_column_1'] = $extra_col[0];
        $results[$key]['extra_column_2'] = $extra_col[1];
    }
}
```

Hope this solution is work for you.